# DataTables Asp.Net MVC export buttons don't work for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using DataTables to show data with opening popup(Kendo Window).(ASP.Net MVC)

Popup comes with a new page. When i try to click Excel and copy button, there is no reaction for Internet Explorer. But when i click a button(not datatable button) to refresh page i can export Excel etc for Internet Explorer.

So i mean when i refresh the page, export buttons(excel, copy) works with IE. Also Google Chrome works very well as usual!

I think i have a problem with JavaScript but i dont know what it is.What is the problem about Internet Explorer?

[Here is discussion but i couldn't get a solution.](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/10406/buttons-work-in-ie-and-chrome-but-shock-horror-not-firefox#Item_11)

Here is my export code

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').dataTable({
            "sDom": 'T<"clear"><"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>',
            "oTableTools": {
                "sSwfPath": "/Scripts/datatables/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": [
                    "xls",
                    "copy",
                    "print",


                ]
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you link to the project / age?

Comment: thanks for your reply.  it's a local project so i cant link to the project.
if you mean DataTables --> http://datatables.net/